# Execute php object method without reloading using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, rss

**Context**

i'm currently working on a school project to create `feed aggregator`.

I'm currently working on `rssfeed` object and therefor it's display.

I wanted to create a function to display the head of the feed with a button which call a method to display all `rss` posts related to this feed

You can see our current version at: http://aaron.tixp.eu/vues/vue_testRSS.php

I already have `RssFeed class` which contains info about it and an array of `RssPost object`.

**Problem**

- The problem is that i don't know how to make the button to call the function to display all the posts.
- Moreover i need this button (or a new button which can replace this one) to reverse the last operation.
- I've already read many solutions but no one for the entire problem and since i have nearly no knowledge on `javascrpit`, `jQuery` or `Ajax` I don't know how to resolve this.

It would be great if someone can help me.

**Solved!**
I updated the code

here's some code:
the file `vue_testrss.php` where i put my tests for rss:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Thomas MEDARD
 * Date: 11/12/15
 * Time: 16:12
 */
require_once '../vues/vue_page-builder.php';
require_once '../controleurs/objetphp/controleur_rssfeed.php';

$scripts = array("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js", "javascript/scroll_to_back_to_top.js");
head('Test', 'salut les coco', 'projet, test, php, yolol', '', $scripts);

if (isset($_GET['rssfeed']) && $_GET['rssfeed'] !== '')
    $url = $_GET['rssfeed'];
else
    $url = 'http://www.legorafi.fr/feed/';
try {
    $flux = new RssFeed($url);
    $flux1 = new RssFeed('http://www.jeuxvideo.com/rss/rss-news.xml');
    $fluxArray = array($flux, $flux1);
    announcement($fluxArray);
}
catch (Exception $e){
    //echo 'Exception : ' . $e->getMessage() . "</br>\n";
    echo 'RSS invalide' . '<br/>' . "\n";
}
echo '        <h1 id="titre">Test RSS</h1><br/>' . "\n";
?>
        <script>
            function collapse_rss(url) {
                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                document.getElementById("expandbutton" + url).innerHTML = "<button type=\"button\" value=\"expand\""
                    + " name=\"expand\" onclick=\"expand_rss('" + url + "')\">Expand</button>";
                document.getElementById("rssposts" + url).innerHTML = "";
            }

            function expand_rss(url){
                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById("expandbutton" + url).innerHTML = "<button type=\"button\"" +
                            " value=\"collapse\" name=\"collapse\" onclick=\"collapse_rss('" + url
                            + "')\">Collapse</button>";
                        document.getElementById("rssposts" + url).innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
                    }
                };
                xhttp.open("POST", "vue_expandajax.php", true);
                xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                xhttp.send("action=expand&url=" + url);
            }
        </script>
        <form id="formulaire-connexion" action="vue_testRSS.php" method="get">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>rss</td>
                    <td><label for="rssfeed"><input id="rssfeed" type="text" name="rssfeed" value=""/></label><br/></td>
                </tr>
        </table>
        </form>

        <div class="menu-vertical">
            <div class="mv-item"><a href="../index.php">accueil</a></div>
        </div>

<?php
if (isset($fluxArray)) {
    foreach ($fluxArray as $value) {
        echo $value->displayHead() . '<br/><br/>';
    }
}
foot();
```

Here is the code to display the RssFeed objects:

```
public function displayHead () {
    $imageLink = isset($this->image) ? $this->image->getUrl() : '';
    $strToReturn = '        <div class="feed">' . "\n"
        . '            <p class="rssfeed">' . "\n"
        . ((isset($this->favicon) || $this->favicon !== '') ?
            '                <img src="' . $this->favicon . '" alt="">' . "\n" : '')
        . '                <a href="' . (isset($this->link) ? $this->link : '') . '">'
            . (isset($this->title) ? $this->title : '') . '</a>' . '<br/>' . "\n"
        . (isset($this->pubDate) ? '                publication date : ' . $this->pubDate . '<br/>' . "\n" : '')
        . (isset($this->lastBuildDate) ? '                last update : ' . $this->lastBuildDate
            . ' <br/>' . "\n" : '')
        . (isset($this->image) ? '                <img src="' . (isset($this->image) ? $imageLink : '') . '" alt="'
            . $this->image->getTitle() . '"> <br/>' . "\n" : '')
        . (isset($this->summary) ? '                ' . $this->summary . '<br/>'  . "\n": '')
            . '            <span id="expandbutton' . $this->url . '"><button type="button" value="expand"
            . name="expand" onclick="'
        . 'expand_rss(\'' . $this->url . '\')">Expand</button></span>' . "\n"
        . '            </p>' . "\n"
        . '            <div id="rssposts' . $this->url . '"></div>' . "\n"
        . '         </div>';
    return $strToReturn;
```

the second one is function which should be called inside the `<div id="rssposts"></div>`:

```
public function displayPosts () {
    $strToReturn = '';
    foreach ($this->rssPosts as $valeur) {
        $strToReturn .= $valeur . "\n"
            . '            <br/><br/>' . "\n\n";
    }
    return $strToReturn;
}
```

For now i'm using the script inside `vue_testrss.php` to write inside the `<div id="rssposts + url"></div>`.
and the file `vue_expandajax.php`:

```
 <?php
require_once '../controleurs/objetphp/controleur_rssfeed.php';
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Thomas
 * Date: 21/12/2015
 * Time: 12:35
 */
if (isset($_POST['action']) && isset($_POST['url'])) {
    switch ($_POST['action']) {
        case 'expand':
            expand($_POST['url']);
            break;
    }
}

function expand($url) {
    $feed = new RssFeed($url);
    echo $feed->displayPosts();
    exit;
}
```

I don't know if it can help but here is a link to the git repositery of the project: https://github.com/Tixp/aaron.git

Comment: Please, reformat your question, struture it, and leave out unneccesary information like _i'm a french student .._ not contibuting to the understandability of your question.

Comment: can you show some code, so we can help you efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having looked at the link and then the source code from the relevant page I knocked this up to help guide you a little. Without seeing the contents of the backend php script we can do no more, but something along these lines might help.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script>
            /*
                This is the contents from javascript/display_10_posts.js
                modified and made into a function that is attached to the button
            */

            function get_rss(){
                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById("rssposts").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
                    }
                };
                xhttp.open("POST", "../vue_expandajax.php", true);
                xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                xhttp.send("action=expand");
            }
        </script>
        <!--
            all other head content
        -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--// Opening html content //-->

        <div class="feed">
       <p class="rssfeed">
           <img alt="" src="http://www.legorafi.fr/wp-content/themes/legorafi/img/icons/favicon-32x32.png">
           <a href="http://www.legorafi.fr">Le Gorafi.fr Gorafi News Network</a><br>
           last update : Fri, 18 Dec 2015 13:00:47 +0000 <br>
           <button onclick="get_rss()" name="expand" value="expand" type="button">Expand</button>
       </p>
       <div id="rssposts"></div>
    </div>

    <!--// remaining html content //-->
    </body>
</html>
```

As an example for the `vue_expander.php` script I tested using the following code. It differs from your code but it was just to test really that it all worked - hopefully you might find it useful.

```
<?php
    /* vue_expander.php */
    $html=array();
    $datasrc='http://www.legorafi.fr/feed/';
    $xml=file_get_contents( $datasrc );

    /* shorthand method to retrieve value from a child node */
    function nodevalue( $node=false, $parent=false ){
        global $xpath;
        return $node && $parent && !empty( $xpath->query( $node, $parent )->item(0)->nodeValue ) ? $xpath->query( $node, $parent )->item(0)->nodeValue : false; 
    }


    /* Create DOM Objects */
    $dom=new DOMDocument('1.0','utf-8');
    $dom->loadXML( $xml );
    $xpath=new DOMXPath( $dom );


    /* Get rudimentary title & description for the RSS feed */
    $root  = $dom->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0);
    $title = nodevalue('title',$root);
    $descr = nodevalue('description',$root);


    /* Begin preparing output */
    $html[]="
        <h1>{$title}</h1>
        <h2>{$descr}</h2>";


    /* Get all items in rss feed */
    $col = $dom->getElementsByTagName('item');
    foreach( $col as $item ){
        /* grab values from childnodes */
        $title = nodevalue('title',$item);
        $comments = nodevalue('comments',$item);
        $link = nodevalue('link',$item);

        /* Other child nodes not calculated but done in same way etc */
        $content = nodevalue('content:encoded',$item);



        $html[]="
        <section>
            <h3>{$title}</h3>
            <p>{$comments}</p>
            <a href='$link'>more..</a>
            <!-- other content here -->
        </section>";
    }
    /* send response back to ajax callback function */
    echo implode( PHP_EOL, $html );
?>
```

Comment: Thank's to help, i'm still actively modifying the code but if you need some of the php code to help tell me i'll pass you

Comment: I see the `get_rss()` function has been applied to the test page and that it sends the request as expected but there is no response sent back from `vue_expandajax.php`

Comment: I know, but if you replace the id in `document.getElementById("rssposts").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;` by something else or if you simply add a wilde echo in `vue_expandajax.php` it displays it on the page. So i don't know why it just doesn't want to write inside the `<div id="rssposts"></div>`